# Find words matching a specific REGEX within a sentence using JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to generate a dynamic message that can be used for processing using Java and Regular Expressions. My incoming value can be just ***"$bdate$"*** or be embedded within a sentence like ***"Your Birthdate : $bdate$".*** I want to replace these ***$aaa$*** values dynamically at run time and am not able to isolate the regex matched values within a sentence. Here is what I have so far....

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {
    public static String REGEX = "\\$((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*))\\$";

    public static String testString = "Summary : $summary$"
                                    + "Age : $age$"
                                    + "Location : $location$"; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Matcher : " + Pattern.matches(REGEX, "$ABX_ 11$"));

        String [] splitStrings = testString.split("\\W+"); //also tried "\\b+"
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(splitStrings);
        for(String test : stringList) {
            System.out.println("Split Word : " + test);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is below - it misses the preceding and succeeding $ symbols:

```
Matcher : true
Split Word : Summary
Split Word : summary
Split Word : Age
Split Word : age
Split Word : Location
Split Word : location
```

I know I am very close but not able to figure out the issue - Can anyone please help !!

Comment: Why are you splitting the strings that way? You are not actually using your regex there.

Comment: To isolate the $aaa$ words so I can replace them with runtime data.

Comment: But you are not using your regex. So you are not actually isolating the `$aaa$` words, you are simply isolating words. The proper way to do this is probably using a `Matcher`, see the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
String pattern = "\\w+|\\$\\w+\\$";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = r.matcher(testString);
while (m.find( )) {
   System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
}
```

See [Ideone DEMO](http://ideone.com/EEo8M7)

Comment: Thanks Karthik, tried your suggestion but get this :                                 Split Word : Summary
Split Word : $summary$Age
Split Word : $age$Location
Split Word : $location$

Guess we need to find words that begin with a $ and end with a $. Not sure what that regex would be.

Comment: Can you please try this within the java program I posted ? the output is different from what you have in the demo.

Comment: @Prashanth what is the expected output?

Comment: each individual word, especially the ones with $xxx$ to be separated. is there any way to get them to separate ? I know that there is no space between the first line in that string and the second line but this is an input from another team - so, I cannot ask them to put a space at the end of each line.

Comment: Maybe a better way is to just extract only the $xxx$ words from the sentence individually using a Regex without parsing through each word like I tried doing ? That will make it easier for me to substitute the values and keep the original string intact as well.

Comment: I will look at a way to extract words that match my pattern as a list and post it when I get it to work but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend @Karthik's answer and complete the thread, below code snippet only looks for words that match a pattern within the sentence and collects them - it might be easier to replace those dynamically at run time.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {
    public static String testString = "Summary : $summary$"
                                    + "Age : $age$"
                                    + "Location : $location$"; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "\\$\\w+\\$";

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        Matcher m = r.matcher(testString);
        while (m.find( )) {
           System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
        }
    }
}
```